# Problems using LightBox 2 with IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, lightbox

I'm having a problem with IE7 when clicking on images that open up using the Lightbox 2 javascript image viewer. Instead of overlaying the image on the current page it opens the image into a separate page.

Not sure if this is an AJAX problem possibly ? Works fine in Firefox.

Anybody else come across this before ?

Comment: Also happens with certain other websites that should refresh in an "Ajax" way. Most sites that use Ajax functionality seem to work fine.

Comment: if the site has a link, that has a target specified IE is likely opening a new tab (e.g. thinking you are targeting a popup window).

I would check that any onclick handlers in links are returning false, esp. if there is a target specified.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is performing the fall-back behaviour you would expect in the following scenarios...

1. JavaScript is disabled
2. There is an error in the JavaScript that is creating the lightbox effect (look out for a very brief flash of the yellow error icon before the next page loads - or fire up some dev tools)
3. There is a JavaScript error on the page *before* the image is clicked, which has stopped execution of JavaScript on the page (look out for the yellow error icon in the status bar again!)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that I have google toolbar amd McAfee security installed that may be blocking the overlay (????) but don't think that should make any difference.